# telegram API automatically join channels

Tags: python, rest, automation, telegram, telethon

Is it possible to join let's say 100 telegram channels from my account if i know these channel id's?
As it's not possible for bots due to telegram API limitations, is this somehow that I could automate my user for? I would like to input telegram id and my account would be join these channels and send a particular message. I researched and found nothing

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

Use this script

https://git.io/Jt9KH

```py
# make sure to have telethon and python-dotenv installed
# create a file called .env in the current directory from where you are running the script
# put API_ID and  API_HASH in the .env file in the following format
# VARIABLE=VALUE


from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import JoinChannelRequest
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import FloodWaitError

from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import asyncio

load_dotenv()
API_ID = os.getenv('API_ID')
API_HASH = os.getenv('API_HASH')


CHANNELS = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # the channels you want to join


async def main():
    async with TelegramClient('tg_session', API_ID, API_HASH) as client:
        for channel in CHANNELS:
            try:
                await client(JoinChannelRequest(channel))
            except FloodWaitError as fwe:
                print(f'Waiting for {fwe}')
                await asyncio.sleep(delay=fwe.seconds)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Here is an example of `.env` file you need to use:

[image: Screenshot from 2021-01-15 17-21-41]

Make sure to have `telethon` and `python-dotenv` installed.